# BackboneJS - How to limit number of models in collection

Tags: backbone.js

How can I set a limit to the number of models to get displayed in collection?

So far I have:

```
var myCollection = new Collection();
myCollection.url = this.model.url() + '/feed';
myCollection.fetch();
```

I have tried to add:

```
myCollection.first(20);
```

but that didnt work, since the `first()` only works on arrays?

Comment: u need only limit in fetch() ?

Comment: `first()` should work fine, but do you wait for `fetch()` to finish before getting the items?

Comment: @jgillich Yes, right now I wait for `fetch()` - should I do `first()` before?

Comment: i think you can use .parse method to slice collection array will be placed in collection  parse: function(response) { return response.slice(0,20) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.parse()` method. It called with `.fetch()` and helps to modify server response.
In your case in may be helpful to slice models array you get from backend.

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.slice(0,20);
    }
});
```

On every fetch you will have first 20 models in your collection.

Comment: Is it possible to add a click event so that when a button is clicked, each time it adds 10 models more?

Comment: Yep, you can call collection fetch on button click. But this case you have to keep some flag on collection instance like isFirstFetch is its true you slice 0,20 else 0,10, and you set this flag to first after first fetch